Why does ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API return chunked response?
I am using an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API with default configuration (new solution, new project, no changes). I noticed that the responses are chunked. Meaning, it returns Transfer-Encoding: chunked response header and does not set the content-length header.
I realize I can change this by adding some middleware code, but it seems like something I would expect .NET to do by default, or at least expose an easy way to change it.
Context: I am using ASP.NET Core Web API hosted on Azure App Service behind Azure front door. Front door needs responses to be not chunked for it to apply compression.

According to your description, you are concernd why .net 8 web api has a default behavior to have Transfer-Encoding response header instand of content-length header, and you want to find a built-in configuration in .Net 8 to change this behavior. I had a test in my side, I create an API endpoint which will return "success" but by default there's no content-length response header. I'm afraid this is due to performance-optimization.
